# Is there a way to show ui in void main method of Flutter integrated native Android Application?

Tags: android, flutter

I have an existing Android Application with Flutter integrated into it.

From a specific native Android fragment I am starting FlutterActivity to launch this Flutter package in my App.

I want to show this android fragment ui only until `runApp` method is called in flutter's entry point `void main()` function of the package but instead i see a blank dark screen.

I understand we can use native android splash screen for standalone flutter Application but what can be done in my scenario to prevent dark screen and show android fragment ui launching flutter activity.